# Getting multiple parts from URL inside of controller

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml, url-pattern

My servlet is mapped with `<url-pattern> /controller/*/* </url-pattern>` my url is like this `controller/12341/ABC123` will always like this but values can be changed.

I am trying to get value of first `*` and second `*` which presents `serial & mac`

I write following code but it return only last part ACB123

```
String mac= request.getPathInfo().replace("/", "");
```

How can I get both vaules?

Comment: Use `split` method and get the last 2 indexes?

Comment: This problem has been solved countless times by many web frameworks... do you really want to "reinvent the wheel" and roll-your-own servlet based solution?

Comment: @LanceJava Thank you, currently I am developing it in custom way. Means not using framework

Answer (score 0):

If I read the servlet spec correctly you cannot have multiple wildcards. Try

```
<url-pattern>/controller/*</url-pattern>
```

And then:

```
String[] parts = request.getPathInfo().split("/");
String serial = parts[1]; // before last index
String mac = parts[2]; // last index
```

Of course you will need some error handling for this.

On a related note: Pure servlet API is a pain to work with. If you have just this only servlet or are constrained somehow, this might be OK. However if you have more servlets and even need HTTP request parameter handling, parsing etc., using a framework like Spring WebMVC might be more appropriate.

Comment: when I `System.out.println("serial: " + serial + ", mac: " + mac);` then my server threw exception: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "12341ABC123"`. Can you please help to figure out problem

Comment: It's rather unlikely that this exception comes from `System.out.println`. I would need to see the full code.

Comment: I have used your code and after that I write `System.out.println(...)` on execution it give exception mentioned previously